# shift+command+L does not work, along with other keybindings. How do I figure out why?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Lots of random commands simply don't work. I don't have any extensions enabled or OS level keybinding apps like karabiner or anything. I checked keyboard settings on mac and disabled anything with SHIFT+CMD+L and I still can't get "Select All Occurrences of Find Match" working in the interactive playground.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, had to restart my computer after disabling the hotkey from keyboard settings. All works well now.